# Swift method chaining, how to reuse classes and methods?

Tags: swift, fluent, method-chaining, methodology

Consider the following example

```
class ClassA {
    
    func createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass() -> AnotherClass {

        return AnotherClass()
    }
    
    func callMeA() {
        
    }
}

class ClassB {
    func createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass() -> AnotherClass {

        return AnotherClass()
    }
    
    func callMeB() {
        
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    func doSomethingAndReturn() {
        return
    }
}

class MethodChain {
    func methodChainTest() {
        ClassA()
            .createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass()
            .doSomethingAndReturn() //return to ClassA
            .callMeA() // call classA callMe
        
        ClassB()
            .createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass()
            .doSomethingAndReturn() // return to ClassB
            .callMeB() // call ClassB callMe
    }
}
```

Is it possible for the class AnotherClass to return the instance of the class that created it?
In this example I want to use the class method doSomethingAndReturn when method chaining with both ClassA and ClassB and then contione the method chain with methods from either ClassA or ClassB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `AnotherClass` generic with a type parameter `Creator`, which stores the type of its creator.

```
class ClassA {
    
    func createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass() -> AnotherClass<ClassA> {

        return AnotherClass(creator: self)
    }
    
    func callMeA() {
        
    }
}

class ClassB {
    func createAnInstanceOfAnotherClass() -> AnotherClass<ClassB> {

        return AnotherClass(creator: self)
    }
    
    func callMeB() {
        
    }
}

class AnotherClass<Creator: AnyObject> {
    // weak to avoid retain cycles!
    private weak var creator: Creator?
    
    init(creator: Creator) {
        self.creator = creator
    }
    
    func doSomethingAndReturn() -> Creator {
        // assuming you always do method chaining, 
        // and not do something weird with the intermediate results,
        // this should be safe to unwrap forcefully
        creator!
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but you run the risk of creating a retain cycle and possible memory leak. I would suggest making the `AnotherClass` `creator` property weak to prevent that.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for the reminder. I didn't think of that! I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Sweeper Does the creator have to be an optional?

is there a reason for not using

private weak var creator: Creator

Comment: @sago92 weak vars must be optional.